# Unable to access bigquery from compute engine with service account included in all roles

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

At first was trying to run a python script using the bigquery client and was getting this error:

```
403 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/**/datasets/newdata/tables/rentaldata: Request had insufficient authentication scopes
```

Then I tried running the bq client:

```
 bq query  --service_account ****-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --nouse_legacy_sql 'select geopoint from `**.newdata.rentaldata`  limit 10'
```

and got this:

```
Waiting on bqjob_rce6575eeefae333_0000016f48c66575_1 ... (0s) Current status: UNKNOWNBigQuery error in query operation: Insufficient Permission
```

The service account is in all the roles possible for bigquery and is also the owner of the project (for testing), any ideas?

The API for bigquery is active.

Comment: The most probable reason is that the GCE instance does not have BigQuery API permissions. If so, you can stop it, edit the scopes and start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Is the service account been previously deleted and recreated using the same account name?

According to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts) [1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts), if a service account is deleted and recreated using the same name, unexpected results might occur. Instead, a new account name should be used.

If using a different service account name is impossible, try following the steps in the same article in order to properly recreate the service account.